# How to update KSQL stream definition dynamically based on schema-registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I created a KSQL stream based on schema-registry by following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425385/how-to-fetch-kafka-source-connector-schema-based-on-connector-name). The Kafka JDBC connector updates a latest schema in schema-registry. The new stream gets created with the latest schema, but existing stream sill in the oldest schema.

I don't know when the schema of the datasource gets changed. In this case, I am expecting KSQL to dynamically refresh its definition with the newest schema available in schema-registry.

Any idea? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you have to manually drop and recreate a stream to pick up the new schema.

I've logged [#2215](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2215) if you want to upvote/discuss desired behaviour there.

Comment: Thank you for opening this issue. I .am watching on this